# Watir - Show_Frames doesn't work

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I want to use show_frames watir command, but it doesn't work. Not for watir, no for watir-webdriver.

Here is sample.

```
irb
require "watir-webdriver"
browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
browser.goto "somewebsite.com"
browser.show_frames
```

NoMethodError: undefined method 'show frames' for #

Any advice?

edit:
here is the new code with output.

```
irb(main):001:0> irb
irb#1(main):001:0> require "watir-webdriver"
=> true
irb#1(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
=> #<Watir::Browser:0x..faae978e6 url="about:blank" title="">
irb#1(main):003:0> browser.goto "iwon.com"
=> "http://www.iwon.com/home/home.jhtml"
irb#1(main):004:0> browser.frames
=> #<Watir::FrameCollection:0x3ab7bd8 @parent=#<Watir::Browser:0x..faae978e6 url
="http://www.iwon.com/home/home.jhtml" title="IWON: The Best Free Online Games,
Casino & Sweeps. Win Money & Prizes!">, @selector={:tag_name=>/^(iframe|frame)$/
}>
```

There is 3 iframes in iwon.com. Other 2 are from ads. I want to monitor ads so I need to scrape contents of those 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pOdeje said in his answer, you need to use .frames

That's only going to return the first level, it will not cover nested frames  (because the content inside a frame acts like its own web-page)

To see those you have to work your way down.

```
browser.frame.frames  #lists frames inside the first frame
```

Note that because it will default to the first instance if you not specify how to find an element, this is the same as saying

```
browser.frame(:index => 0).frames
```

Also of note is that frames will actually return a collection of frames, so you can use pretty much any ruby function that works on a collection.  (note:  In Ruby and other dynamic languages, “Collection” is an umbrella term for general-use lists and hashes. See any good ruby tutorial [like this one](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html), for more info on how to work with collections )

perhaps the most useful of those is .each

```
browser.frames.each do |frame|
  puts "top level frame info :" + frame
  frame.frames.each do |innerframe|
    puts "second tier frame data is: " + innerframe
  end
end
```

that may or may not work depending on if the frame element has a default .to_s defined for it.  if not you may have to tweak the above code to get it to output something reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

That's because there is no `#show_frames` method. It might be wrong, but as far as I understand, it existed in Watir 1, but was removed in Watir 2.

If you want to get the list of all frames, just do `browser.frames`

Comment: Weird. but it only showed 1 of the 3 iframes on the page. 2 are external.

Comment: Try `browser.iframes` or post html code/link so we could take a look.

Comment: @user1237898: Are the frames nested? If they are nested, `browser.frames` will show only parent frames, I think.

Comment: There are 3 iframes on main page, then there are new iframes in 2 of them. What I wanted to accomplish is get iFrame URL, then digg deeper to get the wanted code.

Comment: "can anyone help me here"  firstly did you see the comment about nested frames?  Secondly, to know where you are going wrong, we'll probably need to see a sample of the html